# A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again on mac in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

this code appeared when I tried running and I dont know how to fix it. I am using a Macbook Pro
[image]

Comment: Did you name one of your packages `java`?

Comment: instead of  taking a screenshot of your error, please past it in your question